# How to migrate Netbeans project (with Java DB) from Windows to Linux?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

I had created a project with a JavaDB using Netbeans on Windows, and I would like to move it to my Linux partition. So I copied my project file and I opened it with Netbeans on Linux but I don't know how I can copy the database to use it on Linux! I tried to copy the `netbeans.derby` folder included my database but I don't know where I must to paste it or how I could use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. It's so easy, you must copy your database folder for example Database from the folder .netbeans.derby which is at your user folder. After you will go to paste it at the same direction on the other pc. You will open netbeans and you will connect your database which it will be at the services tab of netbeans. It will be included... You will connect with your username and password and it will be ok!